# Unable to access CRM 2011, Windows Server 2008 - Server is not operational

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtual-machines, virtualbox, microsoft-dynamics-crm

I am new to Dynamics CRM 2011 and trying to use it first time (Running on Virtual Machine). I am getting the following error message in web browser. Any ideas to fix the issue?

> **Business Management Error**
>
> You are attempting to create a user with a domain logon that does not exist. Select another domain logon and try again.

In Trace log, it writes exception error saying `Server is not operational`. When I am trying to create a Domain|User in Active Directory it says `Failed to access the object. Check data availability or access permissions.`